# When it comes to proving equality of functions, curious about valid proof strategies

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, derivatives, proof-writing

Given some information about the functions $B$, $f$ and $g$, how may we prove, for example, the following statement: $$\int_{1}^{B(x)} f(s) \,ds = g(x)?$$ I have a strategy in mind, but I'm not sure if it is valid. Would a valid strategy to prove this statement be to take the derivative of both sides? If I take the derivative of both sides, and this results in some true statement (say $0=0$ or something like that), would that be sufficient proof of the original statement? I am unsure if this would be a valid way of proving a statement like the original one, since implicit in this method of proof is the assumption that the original statement is true from the beginning, when that is exactly what we're trying to prove.

Comment: Please do not vandalize posted questions, including your own. Rolled back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your proposed strategy starts with the required result and has a unidirectional chain of reasoning, due to the [principle of explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion), the proof is indeed invalid.

To be clear, starting a proof with the required statement/result [is perfectly fine](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/24639/372) as long as the logical connective in each step is justifiably and genuinely an equivalence rather than merely an implication. (In the previous link, I also said, “it's anyway easy and always valid to present just the required direction of argument after having used the 'cheat' direction to devise the proof's meat.”)

In this particular exercise, even if it turns out that $0=0$ does imply that the required statement is true up to a constant, this argument in the reverse direction still *has* to be made, for after all what is a proof but a sound argument?

Answer (score 1):

You would prove the statement, *up to a constant*. Remember that two functions have the same derivative iff they differ by a constant, assuming their domain of definition is connected.